# Masking Image with CSS / border-radius

Tags: javascript, css

I'working on a new website for a friend and I'm facing a problem with image that I mask with CSS border-radius.

The image is larger and taller than the container and I use JS to center it properly. However, it seems that Google Chrome and Safari doesn't support what I'm trying to achieve here... It looks nice and smooth on Firefox tough.

I wonder how I could fix that on Chrome and Safari.

Only one image is display currently.

Comment: Link works for me and site is really cool. It looks like overflow: hidden doesn't work for your circle objects in Chrome. Not sure why. You may want to try and post a fiddle that shows just the problem part of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have absolutely positioned `img` elements. If you make the `figure` (their parent) relatively positioned, the images will be centered correctly in chrome.

So, just change the css for `figure` from

```
<figure style="opacity: 0; ">
  <img src="img/pic001_thumb.jpg" title="work 1" style="top: 100px; left: 100px; ">
</figure>
```

to

```
<figure style="position: relative; opacity: 0; ">
  <img src="img/pic001_thumb.jpg" title="work 1" style="top: 100px; left: 100px; ">
</figure>
```

As swatkins pointed out, it seems your javascript is setting different `left` and `top` values for different browsers. I would sugest to fist find a common fix via css.

I don't have FF on this machine, but the `position: relative` might work for that browser too.

Comment: I added position:relative to the figure element but the image is still display weirdly. The round-corner does seems to work for the img.

Comment: @Jk_ my answer was to fix the position. Now the image appears centered. The problem with round corners not working seems to be a Chrome problem, take a look at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71639  You might consider using a transparent png instead of an element with `border-radius`

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your javascript.

In firebug, chrome gives me this:

```
<article class="thumb-container" 
    style="width: 200px; height: 200px; margin-top: 10px; 
           background-color: rgb(216, 228, 125); 
           overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; ">   
    <figure style="opacity: 1; ">
        <img src="img/pic001_thumb.jpg" title="work 1" style="top: 100px; left: 100px; ">
    </figure>
</article>
```

and firefox gives me this:

```
<article class="thumb-container" 
    style="width: 200px; height: 200px; margin-top: 10px; 
           background-color: rgb(216, 228, 125);">  
    <figure style="opacity: 1;">
        <img title="work 1" src="img/pic001_thumb.jpg" style="top: -78px; left: -25px;">
    </figure>
</article>
```

You can see the difference is in your `style` attributes on the `img` tags. I took a quick look at the javascript and didn't see anything glaring, but that would be the place to start.